# How @ControlAdvice captures exceptions?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, exception

I'm on learning phase of Spring boot

I've code where its written like below to handle exception in whole application. Not sure how its working, but I have `NoDataFoundException` class in code and its being used at place where `no data found` issues are happening.

```
@ControlAdvice
class ControllerAdvisor  {

 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
 @ExceptionHandler(NoDataFoundException.class)
 @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNodataFoundException(
        NoDataFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> body = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        body.put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now());
        body.put("message", "No cities found");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

Want to know, how and when `handleNodataFoundException` method automatically gets called when `NoDataFoundException` instance gets created ?

Does spring calls this method  `handleNodataFoundException` on the basis of `@ExceptionHandler(NoDataFoundException.class)` which is bind to method itself and moreover irrespective of name of the method ?

how spring looks for parameters required for above method ? what if it has more parameters in it ?

Comment: Spring will invoke `handleNodataFoundException` whenever your Controller throws (uncaught) `NoDataFoundException`. The method name doesn't matter to Spring. It uses `ControllerAdvice` and `ExceptionHandler` annotations to find and map Exceptions to their respective handler methods.

Comment: @ashu, and all parameters are passing in method should be already existing, so that spring will pick those and pass it. We can n number of parameters here. is it correct ?

Comment: AFAIK, Spring uses type based argument resolvers. So you can have any number of arguments. If all arguments are not resolvable by built-in resolvers, e.g. custom types (not recognised by Spring), you'd have to implement and register your own resolver. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/kdoc-api/spring-framework/org.springframework.web.method.support/-handler-method-argument-resolver/index.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebArgumentResolver.html

Answer (score 0):

This is done by [proxying](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies) ([Proxy.class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)).

Proxying is a mechanism in which a kind of pseudo class is created dynamically and mimics your own class (same methods) and is used to intercept all the method calls. This way it can act before and after the method calls as it please, and in the middle call the real method that you developed.

When you create a `@Service` in Spring, or a `@Stateless` in EJB, you never actually create the instances, you delegate the instance creation on the framework (Spring or EJB). Those frameworks proxy your classes and intercept every call.

In your case, and putting it simple, the proxy has a `catch` around the real call to your method, that `catch` captures exceptions, and acts upon the framework configuration built based on all the annotations that you created (`@ControlAdvice`, `@ExceptionHandler` and so on). And so it can call the `handleNodataFoundException(...)` in the cases that you defined with annotations.

**Update** visualization via stacktrace

For instance, if you have two Spring `@Component` (or `@Service`, `@Repository` or whatever), and one calls the other one in a plain call, and you get an exception, in the stacktrace you see plenty of method calls (involving all kind of different classes) between your two component classes, all those are proxies and framework classes that take care of proxying, invoking, configuration and all the magic that the framework does. And everything is triggered by the proxy of your second component just before calling the real code that you developed, because the first component, at execution time, doesn't really call an instance of your class, but an instance of the proxy of your class that the framework created.

If you run a plain main, with two classes calling one to the other, instantiated by you with `new`, you will only see 3 lines in the stacktrace, because there the instances are plain instances created by you.